# How to remove nth occurrences of a character from string in R?

Tags: r

I have the below character string.

```
"File-2022-03-08-S1-PAR-C-J1-SET"
```

How can I remove the second and third occurrences of the dash (-) symbol and keep all others? Essentially, I'd like the date (2023-03-08) to read 20230308.

Comment: See benchmarking of first 5 working answers somewhere below.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Not sure but do you want result to be something like `File-20220308-S1-PAR-C-J1-SET`

if yes, then this can be achieved using :

```
string <- "File-2022-03-08-S1-PAR-C-J1-SET"

modifiedString <- gsub("-(\\d{4})-(\\d{2})-", "-\\1\\2", string)

modifiedString
```

Answer (score 5):

Using lookarounds.

```
> gsub(r"{-(?=\d{2}\D)}", "", "File-2022-03-08-S1-PAR-C-J1-SET", perl=TRUE)
[1] "File-20220308-S1-PAR-C-J1-SET"
```

Answer (score 3):

Benchmarking for comparison:

```
> library(microbenchmark)
> library(stringr)
> string <- "File-2022-03-08-S1-PAR-C-J1-SET"
> pattern <- "\\b[0-9]{4}-[0-9]{2}-[0-9]{2}\\b"
> microbenchmark(
    Chris = str_remove_all(string, "(?<=\\d)-(?=\\d)"), 
    jay.sf = gsub(r"{-(?=\d{2}\D)}", "", string, perl=TRUE), 
    Manoj = gsub("-(\\d{4})-(\\d{2})-", "-\\1\\2", string), 
    Rui = gsub("(^[^-]*-[^-]*)-([^-]*)-(.*$)", "\\1\\2\\3", string),
    TarJae = str_replace(string, pattern, str_remove_all(str_extract(string, pattern), "-"))
  )
Unit: microseconds
   expr    min      lq     mean  median      uq     max neval
  Chris 28.003 29.1510 31.85003 29.6020 30.8525 177.161   100
 jay.sf  6.027  6.5600  7.13359  6.8265  7.1545  24.272   100
  Manoj  7.093  7.4620  8.17991  7.7490  8.0565  30.094   100
    Rui  8.323  8.8560  9.67641  9.1430  9.5530  19.147   100
 TarJae 68.880 71.2375 74.03329 71.9960 74.5380 129.109   100
```

Comment: Nice and instructive. But speed of execution is not the most important criterion; brevity and transparency are at least equally important.

Comment: @ChrisRuehlemann : I would add specificity. I would judge the contribution fro Manoj as being the most specific because it will only hit dates in the form `dddd-dd-dd` and pass over dashes embedded. I would think a more general approach would also capture dates in the form `dd-dd-dddd` and would award further points for converting to a uniform format with a target of `YYYYMMDD`

Answer (score 2):

Assume that the input is always of the form shown which is a string not containing - and that string is followed by - and the date as shown (namely year which is not 2 characters and then - and the month which is 2 characters and then - and the day).

Then here is a compact base solution which looks for the first occurrence of - followed by two characters and another - and replaces that with those two characters:

```
x <- "File-2022-03-08-S1-PAR-C-J1-SET"
sub("-(..)-", "\\1", x)
## [1] "File-20220308-S1-PAR-C-J1-SET"
```

Answer (score 1):

Here is a base R solution.

```r
x <- "File-2022-03-08-S1-PAR-C-J1-SET"
gsub("(^[^-]*-[^-]*)-([^-]*)-(.*$)", "\\1\\2\\3", x)
#> [1] "File-20220308-S1-PAR-C-J1-SET"
```

<sup>Created on 2023-12-24 with [reprex v2.0.2](https://reprex.tidyverse.org)</sup>

Answer (score 0):

You can use look-around syntax.

That is, you remove the dash character on the condition that `-` is preceded by a `d`igit `(?<=\\d)` and followed by a `d`igit `(?=\\d)`:

```
library(stringr)
str_remove_all(string, "(?<=\\d)-(?=\\d)")
[1] "File-20220308-S1-PAR-C-J1-SET"
```